# Steam client not honouring environment variable when launching through GUI but will if passed in lauched from the terminal

Tags: linux

I'm using PopOS 22.04 trying to use the steam app, deb and tried flatpak versions, having the same issue on both. I have a Hidpi setup and I want to double the size of the steam client.

If I set the variable export GDK_SCALE=2 and launch steam from the GUI, the client is small.

If I launch the client through the terminal without passing any parameters or passing the following the steam client doubles in size.

$ steam GDK_SCALE=2

If I copy the .desktop shortcut from system to my local profile and run it through the GUI, the client is not doubled in size. I did confirm the local shortcut is being run.

I also edited the local shortcut file and added GDK_SCALE=2 to the exec section and it does not double in size.

Seems if I run the steam app through a terminal it works as I expect.

This issue may not be specific to steam.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved.

Terminal looks at your environment variable when launching programs. You can see what your env variables are by the command.

```
export
```

Since I'm logging in through a GUI I had to edit a file that the GUI manager looks at to set env variables. I just put the variables at the bottom on their own line.

```
~/.profile
```

Time saving tips

Using this variable in my .profile doubled everything in my desktop, desktop icons, text etc and it doesn't support fractional numbers, e.g. 1.5

```
GDK_SCALE=2
```

I used this variable that is specific to the steam client that supports fractional numbers.

```
STEAM_FORCE_DESKTOPUI_SCALING=1.5
```